# How do I use Jboss Cache

Tags: netbeans, jboss, gatein

I am trying to build some servlets in Netbeans 7.0 for a web project that is running on/under GateIn - the successor to to Jboss Portal. GateIn comes with and runs JbossCache. I would like to also use JbosCache in my servlets.

How do I import org.jboss.cache.*? I am developing on a Windows box and the GateIn Server is on a HPUX Unix box. If I add the Jar to my project, I can import but then the WAR file will not load in GateIn.